# jquery UI Dialog doesn't see variables defined outside of the dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have TypeScript closure with function body like this where constants defined outside of the dialog().  Inside the Dialog Save button, the variables are undefined.  Please help?  Thanks.

```js
    const oldAnswers: Array<IUserAnswer> = new Array<IUserAnswer>();
    const newAnswers: Array<IUserAnswer> = new Array<IUserAnswer>();
    const updatedAnswers: Array<IUserAnswer> = new Array<IUserAnswer>();
    
    $('form').map(function(){  
        //.....omitted code to change the above variables
    }
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      resizable: true,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Save": function () {
          let thisUrl: string = $('#submit').attr('formAction');
          //ToDo: ajax post here
          let postBackModel: AjaxPostbackModel;
          postBackModel.NewAnswers = newAnswers;
          postBackModel.OldAnswers = oldAnswers;
          postBackModel.UpdatedAnswers = updatedAnswers;
          alert('ToDo: sending ajax postBackModel to ' + thisUrl);
        },
        Cancel: function () {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: u wanna try exporting variables?

Comment: these variables are declared in the same function, so I don't think exporting variables is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response.  I solved the problem.  I didn't initialize the postBackModel in the Save. Here is the correction.

```js
let postBackModel: AjaxPostbackModel = <AjaxPostbackModel>{};
```

utton block.